# In Scala, what does mean .get(0) or .get(1) for a JSON array?

Tags: scala

What does mean .get(0) and .get(1)?

for example in the following code? what are the outputs?

```
  val boardArray = board.asInstanceOf[JSONArray]
  val nameAndResult = boardArray.get(0).asInstanceOf[JSONArray]
  val boardAsString = boardArray.get(1).asInstanceOf[String]
  val name = nameAndResult.get(0).asInstanceOf[String]
  val result = nameAndResult.get(1).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-map-get-method-with-example/

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with **Scala** perse, that is just calling some method on some class. We would need to know which library are you using and more context in order to provide a good answer. - Anyways, I am pretty sure that code is pretty old and was written by a person with little experience in the language; that looks extremely unsafe. - May I recommend checking **circe**, **uJson**, **play-json** or any other modern JSON library.

Comment: It likely means get the item at index passed in parameter. But as said above it really depends on which library you are using. `JSONArray` is not part of standard Scala library.